# Creating a list of days and dates of the month using loops and conditionals

Tags: python-3.x, loops, conditional-statements

I have been trying for 3 days to figure this one out using resources across the internet and am still stumped.  I am new to linux and python. Can anyone help write this so I can see what I am doing wrong?

"Using conditionals and loops, create a program that prints out all the days of the month you're in now, starting with the 1st of the month, and prints out the date and the day of the week in a tidy list."

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to print the days of the current month

```
import calendar
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.now()

year = current_date.year
month = current_date.month

num_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]

day_names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

print(f"Days of {calendar.month_name[month]} {year}:")

for day in range(1, num_days_in_month + 1):
    current_day = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    day_of_week = current_day.weekday()
    print(f"{current_day.strftime('%d')} {day_names[day_of_week]}")
```

And here is the version where if and elseif are used

```
import calendar
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.now()

year = current_date.year
month = current_date.month

num_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]

day_names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

print(f"Days of {calendar.month_name[month]} {year}:")

for day in range(1, num_days_in_month + 1):
    current_day = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    day_of_week = current_day.weekday()
    
    if day_of_week == 0:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[0]}")
    elif day_of_week == 1:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[1]}")
    elif day_of_week == 2:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[2]}")
    elif day_of_week == 3:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[3]}")
    elif day_of_week == 4:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[4]}")
    elif day_of_week == 5:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[5]}")
    elif day_of_week == 6:
        print(f"{current_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is a {day_names[6]}")
```

Comment: This is a great answer, it produced a nice list, thank you!  I am getting very stuck on the conditionals part of the question, however.  Please be nice when I put this code below (haha) I am learning as a new student.  I would like to make a list with if, elif, and else conditions.  When I make my for loops, it loops but produces multiple repeats of the same days.  I could put a "break" but it stops the looping completely and no more dates are produced.  Here is a example of what I was trying to write:

Comment: #Loop through that day's dictionary items
    for key in day.items():

                 #If the key isn't 1, 8, or 15, print the key and value
        if key != ['1' and '8' and '15' and '22' and '29']:
            print('Monday ' + 'October ' + monday['week12'] + ' 2023')
        else:
            pass

                 #If the key isn't 1, 8, or 15, print the key and value
        if key != ['1' and '8' and '15' and '22' and '29' and '2']:
            print('Monday ' + 'October ' + monday['week29'] + ' 2023')
            break

Comment: i edited the answer to add another version of the code with conditionals